# Get UITableView cell height

Tags: ios, uitableview, swift

I have an `UIViewController` that implements both `UITableViewDelegate` and `UITableViewDataSource` and I want to load the screen a bit scrolled down (starting from the 2nd cell). In this case, I tried to set `tableView.contentOffset` to a `CGPointMake` using a hardcoded height, which was the same value I set in the Storyboard for my cell.

However, I want to dynamically read the height. In my table view every cell has the same size, how can I get its height given that in my controller I have my `UITableView` instance?

Here is my code:

```
@IBOutlet var tableView: UITableView!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    // Here instead of 88.0 I wanted something like tableView.cellHeight.
    // Is there something like it? Anyone?

    tableView.contentOffset = CGPointMake(0.0, 88.0)
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The property you're looking for is called `rowHeight`. So ask for `tableView.rowHeight`.

Here are the UITableView docs:

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITableView_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UITableView/rowHeight

They can be very helpful in these situations.

However, I'm not convinced that this is what you really need; it depends on what you mean by "I want to load the screen a bit scrolled down."

Comment: Amazing. That's **precisely** what I wanted. Thank you.

Comment: Okay, but as I say, I'm far from certain that this is going to get you where you want to go! :)

Comment: that's because I guess I couldn't make myself very clear, haha, poor english. I just tested on my iPhone and that's really it.

Answer (score 0):

If you have static `UITableView` cells use:

```
 var height = tableView.rowHeight
```

If you have dynamic cells, you'll have to get it from your `UITableViewDelegate` using an indexPath, in your case, your `UIViewController`:

```
var indexPath = NSIndexPath(row: yourRow, section: yourSection)
var height = tableView(tableView, heightForRowAtIndexPath: indexPath)
```

If you've set an `estimatedRowHeight` you can also check that variable (but it will be zero if you haven't):

```
var height = tableView.estimatedRowHeight
```